# How to do Insertion Sort on Swi Prolog

Tags: sorting, prolog, insertion-sort, declarative

I want to do an insertion sort using rules on swi prolog. At the moment my code looks like
this:

```
isort([H|T],Sorted) :- T = [], Sorted = [H|T].

%When there are only two elements
isort([H1,H2|T],[H2,H1|T]) :- H1 > H2, T = [].
isort([H1,H2|T],[H1,H2|T]) :- H1 < H2, T = [].

%More than two elements
isort([H|T],Sorted) :- isort(T,Sorted).
```

I have tried everything but it all just led to dead ends and end up confusing me even more. Right now, if I query

```
isort([5,4,3,2,1],L).
```

it returns

```
L = [1,2].
```

I do not quite get how the other numbers are not taken care of. Someone please clear off my confusion and possibly enlighten me please.

Comment: In `isort([H|T],Sorted) :- isort(T,Sorted).` you never do anything with `H`.

Comment: Am I supposed to work with it? I coud've just type isort([_|T],Sorted) so as to ignore it.

Comment: Well, if you ignore it, of course it won't be part of the output.

Comment: Well when its included it gives out the wrong answer.

Comment: Your first problem is actually that you have no recursion to handle the tail of any of your patters. Remember that `T = []` at the end of the rule is the same as rewriting the head with `[]` in the place of T, so your second rule (for instance) becomes `isort([H1,H2], [H2,H1]) :- H1 > H2.` Clearly you need to do something about the tail.

Comment: and `isort([5,4,3,2,2],L).` won't even return `[2,2]`, but just fail instead. `isort([],L)` fails too.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is equivalent to

```erlang
isort([H],[H]).                 % a singleton list is sorted

isort([H1,H2],[H1 , H2]) :-     % an ascending list of two elts is sorted
               H1 < H2.    
isort([H1,H2],[H2 , H1]) :-     % a descending list of two elts is
               H2 < H1.         %  sorted, when reversed

isort([H|T],Sorted) :- isort(   % recursion... ?
         T ,Sorted           ).
```

First, what about `isort([],[]).`? Isn't an empty list already sorted?

Second, what about `isort([H1,H2],[H1 , H2]):- H1 =:= H2.`? Isn't a list of two equal elements already sorted?

Lastly, the recursion. What about actually *inserting* your `H` into *the result* of sorting the rest of the list, `T`?

```erlang
isort( [H|T],      S ) :-       % [H|T] sorted is       S, *if*
   isort( T,  TS ),             %    T  sorted is TS, *and*
   insert( H, TS,  S ).         % H inserted into TS is S
```

Now all that is left here to do is to define `insert/3`.

Comment: Was this helpful at all? Is something still unclear? Don't hesitate to ask.